# is there a way to pass inline style rules to all children?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style a post on an internet forum that doesn't allow stylesheets, only inline styles.  But it seems that inline styles don't get inherited by children, only the text immediately below (for instance using <h1> will remove the background color from the text).  Is there any way to make it pass the styles down without having to add them to every node?

Comment: Inline styles are inherited normally: http://jsfiddle.net/fRpQ2/ Please provide a more detailed example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

although @SimeVidas is right, I think his response was a bit quick. Some caution do is required. I updated his fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fRpQ2/4/ to demonstrate.

If a specific property is declared in the stylesheet for a given tag, that value will NOT be inherited from the parent with the inline style. I guess this is what you are encountering on the forum post you try to style. Nothing to do about this without using style-tags or linked stylesheets. Just a lot of copying required in your case I'm afraid. You could also inspect the site and apply existing classes to your post, but that is only if you want to copy the styling they already apply wich i doubt is the case.

I would advice you to do some reading on the cascading order of styles if you want to learn more.

Comment: Your link is the same as Šime Vidas'.

Answer (score 0):

couldn't you just also define a `<style>` block if the forum parses html?

Comment: No, it ends up showing the stylesheet in the post unfortunately.

Comment: style blocks are not valid html when placed inside the body, only allowed in the head of the page